# Why is "Is there a way to run Python on Android?" closed as off-topic [asking for recommendation]?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[Is there a way to run Python on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101754/is-there-a-way-to-run-python-on-android)

While the question is poorly worded, it clearly asks if it's possible to write a program in a specified programming language (Python) for a specified target platforms (Android).

Closed as off-topic. Reason:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource [...]"

- How is this a software recommendation question?
- On which SE site would it be appropriate to ask such a question, if not on SO?

Comment: Look at the answers -- did I miss one that *wasn't* a software recommendation? Based solely on the question, a better close reason might be "Too Broad", but it's still closeable.

Comment: Looks like Tim reopened it a few years back, and then it was closed again last year.  Might be a good idea to read the comment history, I bet.

Comment: @PaulRoub I'm glad you mentioned the answers. They are terrible. Is it a settled matter that it's ever OK to close a question based on existing answers?

Comment: Well, bad questions attract bad answers. The answer to _Is there a way to run Python on Android?_ is _Yes_, but yes/no questions are a bad fit for SO and tend to be closed for a variety of reasons depending on how you interpret the question (too broad if you assume OP wants an answer explaining how, resource recommendation if you assume OP wants a tool/tutorial, unclear if you can't determine what OP wants).

Comment: But what's really a software recommendation? Is "how to do X" (where X is a problem strictly related to developing software) really a recommendation question? Isn't recommendation something like "Could you recommend me a good programming language, I'm a beginner" or "Which Python implementation would you recommend me? I'm Microsoft Windows fan?"?

Comment: Is this a recommendation question? (+1140, open)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file?rq=1

Comment: If I play Devil's advocate for a second: Aren't we telling people "to get your recommendation question reopened, just ask about the problem you have. If the answers are recommendations, so be it". What's different here? I can't see it, honestly :/

Comment: @Patrice But that's my point, and I'm not a devil's advocate here. I can't see why it's bad if you ask a software development question and the answer involves recommending software. Obviously, all rules about writing a good answer apply! But I believe that answers are by definition a totally another story.

Comment: @cubuspl42 No, that does not appear to be a library/off-site resource recommendation question. The answers there also (for the most part) seem to provide quite detailed instructions on how to actually accomplish OP's task.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question is pretty terse; it discusses APIs, then a lack of an API, then asks how to do something broad in a language. OK, this may be better closed as Too Broad at this point, but we didn't catch it then (or at least, I didn't).

When I saw the question, 49 answers had been added, all of which are library recommendations. To their credit, one or two give some explanation. Unfortunately, neither of the two answers that provide some explanation on how to do what OP asked were accepted. The answer that *was* accepted is a library recommendation.

This is a pretty clear indication by a number of means that this question should be closed:

- OP asked a question that's too broad and/or arguably about getting a library/API recommendation
- OP accepted an answer that is recommending a library/resource (and nothing else), indicating to us that OP was probably only interested in a library to begin with
- People continue to post answers that do nothing but recommend libraries, which is the kind of content we don't really want on Stack Overflow

It's important to keep in mind that we *do* have a practice of not reopening questions just to close them for a different/better reason, if the question is in fact one that should be closed (unless you're a moderator and can do it yourself with two clicks).

So if you ever come across a question that is closed, and you're thinking "huh, that close reason doesn't make much sense", the question you should ask yourself is "should this question be *reopened*", not "how is this close reason accurate? I don't think it is, therefore it should be reopened".

The exception to this is if a question is closed as a duplicate and you don't feel the duplicate is accurate or that there might be a better question to serve as a dupe target. That's a scenario where we want to remedy the signpost to be as correct as possible.

Comment: Note that in case of wrong duplicate it is better to use (or find) gold-hammer and  *edit* list of duplicates (either replace or add) rather than vote to re-open and wait for 10 people to agree on re-open/re-close.

Answer (score 7):

A quick glance at the last few answers from the last two years indicates that people believe that it's okay to just recommend whatever library they wish for someone to get their Python code working on Android.

In essence, that fulfills the second half of the close reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow **as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.**

So instead of letting *that* continue, the best thing to do would be to close the question.

It doesn't even look like any of them are actually about running actual Python code on Android.  It's all discussing cross-compilation which doesn't *appear* to be the thrust of the OP anyway.

Comment: But isn't the second part of the close reason just a comment to the first one? _You can't ask about <X>, because <justification>_. I believe that justification is relevant if and *only* if your question was about <X>.

Comment: @cubuspl42 Only 2 of the 49 answers actually suggest a way to do it. The others (including the myriad deleted ones) just recommend a library. Couple the fact that  users are treating it as a high-exposure dumping ground for their favorite library with the fact that OP *accepted a library recommendation as the answer* and it seems to clear to me that the entire Q&A chain is really just about library recommendations.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'll repeat it once again: do you really believe that closing questions is a tool for judging bad answers?

Comment: @cubuspl42:  The intent of closing the question is so that it *can't* receive bad answers, with some hope that the OP will actually fix the issue with the problem if they can.  Obviously that didn't happen soon enough for this one, but we can at least stop the bleeding *now*.

Comment: I'm not telling that that question and its answers "nice". The result it's terrible. But what is the conclusion? The question cannot be re-asked, because it will be insta closed as a duplicate, and the original question is closed based on answers...

Comment: @cubuspl42 What are you really asking? Are you wanting to ask the same question of "can I run Python on Android?" What part of that question is not already answered by plethora the existing answers? If you want to ask something that's not covered by the existing answers, then it sounds like you have a *different question*.

Comment: @Makoto Are there any relevant guidelines by SO creators / mods? Ones that apporve using close mechanism in this way? I tried to find something in the docs / on meta without success.

Comment: @TylerH I'm asking what I'm asking, which is "why is the mentioned question was closed with the specified reason?". For now, the only answer is "it received bad answers, so it was closed". And, well, I don't like this answer, to be honest.

Comment: @TylerH If you have a better answer than "because it got bad answers" then please post it.

Comment: @cubuspl42 That's a bit misrepresentative of what Makoto's answer says. My answer is the same: the question was broad and referenced trying to find a library. **40+ answers** were provided that suggested libraries. OP accepted an answer that recommended a library. What's *not* acceptable about closing such a question as a library recommendation question?

Comment: @TylerH What _is_ acceptable about that? You just told that a) it's acceptable to close questions based on what kind of google traffic they get b) it's acceptable to close questions based on answers. I strongly believe that neither a) nor b) is obvious (intuitive) or that SO creators/admins ever suggested that this tool (closing) can be ever used for either of this reason. For a) you have "protection" mechanism, for b) you have downvotes, which _obviously_ don't always work, because are casted by users who don't know or respect SO rules.

Comment: @cubuspl42 No, I didn't say anything about Google traffic; please be more careful when describing what others are saying... so far you've not been very accurate at it. Also, the protection mechanism is to prevent spam, VLQ/NAA posts from new users, not for handling off-topic subjects, and it's also ideally a temporary measure. To be clear, I'm saying it's acceptable to close a question based on OP's reveal of what their concern is. OP, by accepting a library recommendation answer, indicated to us that his question was about getting a library. I'm inclined to believe OP.

Comment: @cubuspl42 If you want to ask why we should be closing library requests as off-topic (regarding "What *is* acceptable about that?"), that's a separate conversation.

Comment: @TylerH I'm willing to accept the answer "because the acceptance marker can be considered a part of a question" if you'd like to post it.